# Best practice when passing data with HyperLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a a dynamically created list with HyperLinks and they all link to the same page and i need them to tell the second page who they are so i can do the correct stuff depending on which link was clicked.

I have read so much about all the "right" ways and none really offers any help, if they was not suggesting that i change my hyperlink to a button instead which i cant due to style issue.

What is the best way to do this?

My thought was to add something that saved a value to a viewstate in the aspx file and then in the second page aspx.cs file i get the value and use it in the creation of the second page depending on which value was collected.

Comment: `<asp:LinkButton>` - no more style issue. The "saved value in `ViewState` in this case can probably be the built-in `CommandArgument` property. (You can put a chunk of JSON there if you need to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically you've got many options. Just to name a few:

1. Dynamically add a query string parameter to the end of each link's URL. For example `/second-page?link-id=like` and `/second-page?link-id=dislike`. Then on the second page, read this value.
2. On the client side, hook into the `click` event of each link, and just before letting the browser to navigate, set a cookie which would be sent to the server and would be accessible in the second page.